# Update quantity of an existing product in shopping cart in laravel and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building a shopping cart in vuejs, when I add my product, someone who can help me insert it again instead of increasing the amount.
thanks.

COMPONENT 1
this is the body of my table where I render my cart

```
<tbody >
<tr v-for="(ProductCart, index) in carrito" :key="index.id">
    <td>{{ProductCart.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ProductCart.cantidad}}</td>
    <td>{{ProductCart.precio}}</td>
    <td>{{ProductCart.cantidad * ProductCart.precio}}</td>
    <td> 
        <form  method="post">
            <input :value="csrf" type="hidden" name="_token" >
            <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="" >
            <button  class="btn btn-success" type="submit"> Remove</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
    <td>
    <h5>Total</h5>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
    <h5>{{ total }}</h5>
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

script

```
<script >
import Axios from 'axios'
import EventBus from '../event-bus'
export default {

data(){
    return{
        csrf: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
        carrito: [],
    }
},

created: function(data){
    EventBus.$on('agregado', (data) => {
        this.carrito.push(data);
    })
},

mounted(){
    Axios.get('carrito')
    .then(Response => {this.carrito = Response.data})
},

computed: {
    //fincion total 
    total: function () {
        let total = 0; 
        Object.values(this.carrito).forEach( 
            (item) => (total += item.precio * item.cantidad) 
        );
        return total.toFixed(2); 
    },
    cantidad: function(){

    }
},
}
</script>
```

component content where is the compass cart
form button which executes the method

```
<button v-on:click="addproduct" class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit"> Add</button>
```

this is the content of the data

```
data(){
return {
    csrf: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,

    Productos:{
        id: 1,
        name: 'producto 3',
        precio: 1,
        cantidad: 1,
    }
}
},
```

method to add product

```
addproduct: async function () {
    
    axios.post('sales/item', {
        
        id: this.Productos.id,
        name: this.Productos.name,
        precio: this.Productos.precio,
        cantidad: this.Productos.cantidad,

    })
    .then(function(response){
        
        EventBus.$emit('agregado', response.data)

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response);
    });

},
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not very clear. Can you rephrase what you are trying to do, and exactly what is happening when you attempt  to do it?